# Magento 2.2.1 - Remove Free Shipping for a Specific Product

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping, magento-2.2.1

I recently upgraded to Magento 2.2.1 and there are 3 products that I make and sell. I recently set up free shipping for any orders over $500. However, for these 3 products, I need to remove the free shipping. Is there a way you can do this in Magento 2 or do I need an extension to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have to manage free shipping using `Magento Free Shipping Method` Not using Cart rules.

Create a Plugin in `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping`
and    Create around plugin on aroundCollectRates and restrict the freehsipping on Product Sku.

```
<?php


namespace StackExchanges\OnlyMagento\Plugin\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model;

class FreeshippingPlugin {
    public function aroundCollectRates(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    ){
        $disableskus = ['sku1','sku2','sku3'];

        if (!$subject->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        $items = $request->getAllItems();
        $hasrestricProduct = false;
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $item->getProduct()->getSku();
            if(in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $disableskus)){
                $hasrestricProduct = true;
            }
        }
        if($hasrestricProduct){
             return false;
        }
        return $proceed($request);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to be perfect moderator !!!

Comment: So I would copy this and add my SKU's in place of this line, right?

`$disableskus = ['sku1','sku2','sku3'];`

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: So is this supposed to be a separate file, or am I editing a current file? If there is a separate file, I'm not sure where to save it.